# Go through N for loops where N is a variable

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.6, permutation

So I have this problem:
Imagine having a variable "N" which is an integer.
What I want is to make all combinations of values for this number of "spaces", an example to make it easier:

```
N = 2
result = []
for i in range(0,100,25):
    for j in range(0,100,25):
        result.append((i,j))
print(result)
```

this will give
 `result = [(0, 0), (0, 25), (0, 50), (0, 75), (25, 0), (25, 25), (25, 50), (25, 75), (50, 0), (50, 25), (50, 50), (50, 75), (75, 0), (75, 25), (75, 50), (75, 75)]`

The objective is to give all the combinations between 0 and 100 with a 25 step.
The same would go for 3 variables... `[(0,0,0),(0,0,25),...,(25,50,50),...]`
 If I wanted N = 3 I had to use 3 for cycles. I want to know how can I program this in a different way so that I can input any N and it gives the proper result.

Comment: is this homework? are there any restrictions?

Comment: No, this isn't homework., it's to create a state space. The range is the same for every variable which should make it easier.

Comment: Maybe try thinking about it like you are counting in quarter-nary (with 4 digits). First you count up to 100 in the least significant place, going up by a step of 25 each time. Then, when you hit 100, you add 25 to the next least significant place, etc. Doing something like this should be easy to generalize.

Comment: I see, that would be a good hand made alternative @agaidis . From the answers I've seen that there is the module product from itertools that's literally made to do this. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a cartesian product of several lists, and there is function `product` in module `itertools` which does just that:

```
from itertools import product
result = list(product(range(0,100,25),
                      range(0,100,25)))
#[(0, 0), (0, 25), (0, 50), (0, 75), (25, 0), (25, 25), 
# (25, 50), (25, 75), (50, 0), (50, 25), (50, 50), 
# (50, 75), (75, 0), (75, 25), (75, 50), (75, 75)]
```

You can pass as many ranges as you want, and they don't have to be the same.

If you later plan to use the generated tuples in a loop, do not coerce the result of `product` into a list:

```
for tup in product(range(0,100,25), ...):
    do_something_with(tup)
```

Comment: Why wouldn't I still save it in a list to use later?

Comment: To save space, as a cartesian product may be quite large.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import product

N = 2
START = 0
END = 100
STEP = 25

rng = range(START, END, STEP)

for tup in product(rng, repeat = N):
    print(tup)
```